# Can't find AVD or SDK manager in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-virtual-device

Seems like I'm having some problems after updating my android sdk tools and platform-tools using the sdk manager. The problem is that, after updating, I found that the avd or sdk options in the windows dropdown menu in eclipse are gone! And, I can't find any option to create an android project from file->new projects any more.

I tried removing the ADT from eclipse and the software site "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" from "available software sites" and then reinstalled the ADT from "https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/" using help->install new software. The installation was successful, but I still don't have any option for shortcuts to the SDK manager or the AVD in eclipse, and neither can I create a new android project.

By the way, the android perspectives are not gone, they are still here. Also, I can manually open the avd and sdk manager from the directory where I have installed them.

Can anyone please show me a workaround? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: not a lot of information there, can you post a screenshot of what is not showing up.

Comment: as these snaps show, i've installed the adt, but cant create new android project, or see the avd and sdk managers in windows menu

Comment: there are no snaps in your post, probably try nandeesh answer

Answer (score 334, accepted):

I have solved this as follows:

1. Window > Customize Perspective... (you will see Android and AVD Manager are disabled)
2. Command Groups Availability > Android and AVD Manager > check
3. Tool Bar Visibility > Android and AVD Manager > check

Comment: Yes, this worked for me too. Eclipse crashed, and then the Window > Android SDK Manager menu was gone, this brings it back.

Comment: Awesome!  It was the perfect fix for me.  This post also put me in the spot to find out that I could customize my toolbar and take out all the options that I have never used.

Comment: yeah...it worked...i didnt knew til today we can customize eclipse toolbar....thnx...

Comment: @joseluismms, Its: Window > Customize Perspective...fix it :-)

Comment: When I create new workspace, the android options was gone. Thanks for your answer, help me a lot.

Comment: I installed a Windows 64 bit version from scratch, and this setting is not set.  Thanks for the help.  I had tried re-installing a number of times.

Comment: i had to also go to the shorcuts tab >> check "android" in the shortcuts menu

Comment: This was hidden by default in Eclipse on OSX, so very helpful

Answer (score 15):

I had similar problem after updating SDK from r20 to r21, but all I missed was the SDK/AVD Manager and running into this post while searching for the answer.

I managed to solve it by going to `Window -> Customize Perspective`, and under Command Groups Availability tab check the Android SDK and AVD Manager (not sure why it became unchecked because it was there before). I'm using Mac by the way, in case the menu option looks different.

Answer (score 5):

Well I feel silly, but my problem was that I was in the Debug perspective and they do not show up in that perspective.  Switched back to the Java perspective and viola.

Answer (score 5):

Window -> Custom Perspective -> Command Groups Availability -> Android SDK and AVD Manager  check it

Answer (score 3):

Chances are that you may be running your eclipse using Java 1.5.

```
Latest Plugin requires that the JRE be 1.6 or higher.
```

You will have to use Eclipse that runs on JRE 1.6

Edit: I had run into same problems. If it is not JRE problem then you can debug this. Follow  below procedure:

1. Window -> show View -> other -> Plugin Development -> Plugin Registry
2. In the plugin registry search for com.android.ide.eclipse.adt or any other plugin related   to android (depending on your installation there maybe 7-8)
3. Select , Right Click -> Diagnose. This will show the problem why the plugin was not loaded

Comment: You're right! high chances are there i'm using the wrong eclipse package. i'll try downloading the right one. Can you please give me the name of the right package, or a link maybe ?

Comment: can't find plugin development
here's the snap: [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/64949901/pl.jpg)

Comment: you have a minimal installation of eclipse. I guess downloading new [eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall **ADT plugin** on Eclipse. Check out this:
[Installing the Eclipse Plugin](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to install the ADT plugin compatable with your Android SDK tools and try to install all the required plugins compatable with your Android SDK
LIKE
    Android SDK tools Rev 20.0.3
    Android SDK tools Rev 20.0.3
    Android SDK Platform-tools Rev 14
    Android 2.3.3(API 10) sdk platform rev 2
    samples for sdk api 10 rev 1
    ADT Plugin 20.0.3

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I ended up having to re-install eclipse. but first (In Linux)(not sure of folder in Windows) do:

```
sudo rm -R /usr/share/eclipse/
```