# Android not appearing in Eclipse -> Preferences (OS X 10.5.8)

Tags: android, eclipse, macos

I've tried Eclipse Classic 4.2, 3.5, 3.7.2, and Java EE.  I've attempted to install the ADT plugin on each version, and most seem to have no trouble at all.  But when Eclipse restarts, Android preferences are never available (though the files are clearly in my plugins folder).  I've even tried eclipse -clean park, but no luck.

Man, setup was going so smoothly until now...  Any ideas?

Comment: have you checked this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028811/cant-find-avd-or-sdk-manager-in-eclipse/12029011#12029011?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, here's the diagnosis:  The following problems were found:
  Missing Constraint: Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
  Missing required bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.base_0.0.0
  Missing required bundle com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms_0.0.0

Comment: That means you are using Java 1.5 execution environment. You need to get eclipse that runs on 1.6

Comment: I know this is a stupid question, but you mean the issue is just with the version of Eclipse?  It's not obvious to me which one I should be using.  I know I have the option to manually set the execution environment when creating projects, and JavaSE 1.6 appears to be available, so why isn't that being used?  Sorry, this compatibility stuff is somewhat nebulous to me.  I just want to get coding! lol

Comment: The setting you are referring to is applied only for a project, plugin requires it to be across eclipse. I think there might be an option to change on which execution environment the eclipse runs, but I do not know how.  you could post one more question here or on eclipse forum asking how to change execution environment for whole eclipse. But what I have seen is eclipse Juno works

Comment: Actually, I think the problem is the reverse:  the ADT plugin needs JavaSE 1.6 and I have 1.5.  I thought I had successfully updated it through Terminal, but apparently I can't get 1.6 without updating OS X (which doesn't really make sense to me).  But I can't update right now because I have important software on my machine that would be broken.  So now I'm trying to use a previous version of Android, but I can't find android-sdk_r15-macosx on the site.  I have to admit, my ancient PC doesn't have nearly as many compatibility issues as my relatively new MacBook Pro.  What a headache...

Comment: Did you try,by getting eclipse Juno?

Comment: Yeah, that's the one I've been using, but no luck.  I did find SDK r15, but I'm having some trouble setting it up with Eclipse.  I think I've decided just to do my Android development only on my PC for now.  It doesn't recognize my phone, but I'll just use the emulator.  Thanks so much for everything nandeesh.  Your advice was very helpful.