# Eclipse - Android configuration problems

Tags: java, android, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find older versions of Eclipse ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt)
>   [Can’t find AVD or SDK manager in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028811/cant-find-avd-or-sdk-manager-in-eclipse)

I'm having difficult installing the Android environment on Eclipse. I've tried all the usual fixes like running as an administrator but have had no success.

I have installed the ADT Plugin which has been checked multiple times but when I restart Eclipse and go to Window-Perspective Android does not appear. I'm making this a new question because all of the solutions I have tried and none have worked.

Eclipse version - Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

I have download the Android SDK and that's fine but can't seem to get to work with Eclipse. Grrr!

Anyone got any ideas?

P.S. I have tried using Eclipse Classic and the problems are still the same.

SOLUTION FOUND: [Where can I find older versions of Eclipse ADT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710107/where-can-i-find-older-versions-of-eclipse-adt) older versions of ADT can be found here to work with the Java version I have. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: There is no Android perspective. Are you able to create an Android project? If yes, you are good to go.

Comment: Do you have deep-freeze in your pc ?

Comment: I'm not able to create an Android Project no. I can't even get to the stage where the SDK is available.

Comment: What version of Eclipse (Indigo, June, other) are you using?

Comment: @Dan I am using Eclipse Juno, attempting to use Indigo now.

Comment: Sometimes the ADT plugin does not get installed correctly. I usually remove Eclipse's configuration and metadata and it works. I'm using Juno Classic.

Comment: @nandeesh How can I upgrade the JRE?

Comment: do check whether it is the same problem? by going to eclipse Plugin Registry. Check what java version you are using

Comment: I am using version 1.5 of Java. Unfortunately the system administrator in work tells me that they have to use that because the work other people are doing requires 1.5. Is there a way I can get an older version of the ADT to work with 1.5?

Answer (score 1):

- http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html

If you will be developing in Eclipse with the ADT Plugin, first make sure that you have a suitable version of Eclipse installed on your computer as described by the system requirements.

If you need to install Eclipse, you can download it from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/. We `recommend` the "`Eclipse Classic`" version. Otherwise, you should use a Java or RCP version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You need

- java JDK
- Android sdk
- ADT plugins
- Eclipse

in eclipse goto -> help -> install new soft-> select ADT XX...

then Goto windows -> preferences -> set android sdk path

also see this link for [STEP BY STEP TUTORIAL](http://developer-android.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-install-android-step-by-step.html)

Comment: I have done this multiple times, I work at different work stations so have followed these steps many times.

Comment: try to delete your old eclipse and extract new copy of eclipse

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to install the ADT plugin for Eclipse Juno either, so I had to stay with Eclipse Indigo for a while. I noticed that others had the same issue.

Comment: Works for me (Juno Mobile and Juno Classic).