# Can't see Android in Prespetive ,SDK Manager & AVD Manager .

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, upgrade, ubuntu-12.04

I just upgraded my Ubuntu to 12.04 & now when i run my eclipse so it runs file but the problem is that i can't find android any where. Even i try to update ADT etc but it tells that everything is already installed . Stuck badly anyone can help. I can't see Android in Prespetive , it's SDK Manager & AVD Manager & even in new project i can't find android application .

Comment: goto window -> customize perspective -> command group availability -> and then tick on the android options given there then you will be able to see everything

Comment: if you have installed every thing properly then the above thing works :)

Comment: @ Auto Droid Last time when i face this type of problem i just did whatever you told. But now this time i can't even see any android options in window -> customize perspective -> command group availability -> ..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028811/cant-find-avd-or-sdk-manager-in-eclipse

Comment: That answer didn't help  me out. So now i uninstalled ADT plugin of android & reinstalling it. Hope this will work .:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your eclipse/plugins directory. Can you see com.android.ide.eclipse.{adt,base,ddms,etc...}.version_number.jar files? If not, then you need to reinstall eclipse ADT plugin.

Comment: yes pakages are exists in plugin directory . Another problem which i can see is that in Prespective <java> is not working .

Comment: Probably your eclipse config is foobared due by the ubuntu upgrade. Unless you want to research this issue (which is because of the ubuntu upgrade and therefore this becomes a question for superuser), you can remove eclipse and eclipse config (from your ~/.config). i suggest downloading a fresh ADT bundle.