# Eclipse stuck while creating application in Ubuntu

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

I created a new Android Application project on my Ubuntu computer. After giving names to all required fields, at the last step (name activity), Eclipse is somewhat frozen. I'm not sure what to do next.

Here's a snapshot:

[image]

All the necessary components(SDK, latest packages) are already installed. If I try to hit the close icon, or click "quit" from the sidebar on the left, it says something about Press cancel to ... (screenshot below):

[image]

The "Android SDK build tools marker" progress bar at the bottom right end of the window is moving back and forth, but other than that, the whole thing is just stuck. Been about 20 minutes now.

Please help.
Oh, and this is the first time I'm running ADT on this Ubuntu computer.

========================================================

EDIT-1

I restarted Eclipse after restarting the computer, but when I restarted Eclipse, I noticed all Android related tools were gone. It was just barebones Eclipse that you can see when you download Eclipse for the first time.
I installed the ADT Plugin from the [Android website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html). It was installed successfully, and Eclipse restarted. However, there was no pop-up which usually appears with a Dialog Box saying something like "SDK preferences not setup". Further, I couldn't find the pane on top which has icons for SDK Manager, or the emulator.

Here's the latest screenshot:

[image]

How do I get the missing Android related tools?

I'm going through this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028811/cant-find-avd-or-sdk-manager-in-eclipse), but doesn't look like it'll help.

==========================================

EDIT-2

I've been able to bring the SDK and AVD icon in the toolbar, but the red errors, shown in previous snapshot, are still there. Not sure what the problem is. SDK Manager says everything is updated:

[image]

I've gone through most of the available solutions to the missing R.java (yes, R.java is indeed missing from my app) problem, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824730/r-cannot-be-resolved-to-a-variable) and [this](http://www.mybringback.com/android-sdk/1/hello-world/) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/rCaeT3qckoE) and many more, but nothing helps.

Comment: Why don't you try using Android Studio, since it is the official IDE for Android.

Comment: Perhaps something went wrong with installation.  You could try to completely uninstall then re install eclipse and see if that fix's it.

Comment: Please see my update above. I restarted computer and eclipse, but that only resolved the problem partially.

Comment: Eclipse is very annoying like this sometimes.  Make sure everything from the sdk manager is installed. I've had this error many times and found that I had to install build tools, android version sdk packages and restart ,in my case, Android studio(but I'm pretty sure that it works the same with eclipse). I also recommend that you try Android Studio, as its essentially the same and might work better for you. Hope you get this problem figured out.

Comment: Also make sure to try to import R.java, if you haven't already.