# eclipse not finding path for sdk on linux ubuntu

Tags: android

I've installed eclipse and sdk onto linux ubuntu successfully. I can write codes in eclipse fine. However, when trying to use sdk with eclipse its not finding the path. For instance: opening up clipse then help then install new software and since I have no Internet connection at home I go to add then local and find android sdk in here: /home/myusername/Downloads/android-sdk-linux I click on it and it puts that path into the empty bar. I click add or o.k and a message pops up "can't find file:/home/myusername/Downloads/android-sdk-linux why is eclipse not finding sdk? Can someone help please. 
Thanks
Nick

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't find AVD or SDK manager in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12028811/cant-find-avd-or-sdk-manager-in-eclipse)

Comment: Hi,GaurawYadav                                                                                          Yeah, I would do that if I could see android there. Obviously its not finding it. That's my dilemma. eclipse is not finding the path to sdk, There is no android anywhere to click on. Not in windows>preferences and under help>install new software it will not find the path to it. Eclipse is not seeing skd at all. That's why its not displaying it under windows?preferences either. I'd like to find out how to fix this.

Comment: Hi,GaurawYadav                                                                                          Yeah, I would do that if I could see android there. Obviously its not finding it. That's my dilemma. eclipse is not finding the path to sdk, There is no android anywhere to click on. Not in windows>preferences and under help>install new software it will not find the path to it. Eclipse is not seeing sdk at all. That's why its not displaying it under windows>preferences either. I'd like to find out how to fix this.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window>preferences> select Android from left Panel> paste your SDK directory click apply and then OK.